# How to create SQL-Query to update data in tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update data in my table.

I have two tables, t1 and t2

T1[image: first table]

T2[image: second table]

I'm want to do, that if t1 have `id_avito = null` and `all_usl_name = %usl_name1%` and `all_tel = %tel1%`, and t2 have `id != null`, `usl_name = %usl_name1%` and `tel = %tel1%`

For example, t1 after execute query must to look like that[image: updated t1]

```
update people.t1, people.t2
set 
    id_avito = people.t2.id, 
    lnk_avito = people.t2.link, 
    all_price = people.t2.price,
    all_date = people.t2.date, 
    all_adr = people.t2.adr,
    all_usl_name = people.t2.usl_name 
where id_avito != people.t2.id
and all_tel= people.t2.tel 
and all_usl_type = people.t2.usl_type
```

I try to do like this, but it is not working

**UPD**

EXAMPLE: [tables](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d114bb1b12a34e40cb4219c891c758f). Table before update, after update, and second table

Comment: "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Which _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, DB2, etc.) ?  Also, if possible, please include your sample data as _text_ directly in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using MySQL 5.0,7, about data, one minute please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with update join also you need to use like operator where you are searching with string

```
update people.t1 a  
join people.t2 on id_avito != people.t2.id
and all_tel= people.t2.tel 
and all_usl_type = people.t2.usl_type
set 
    id_avito = people.t2.id, 
    lnk_avito = people.t2.link, 
    all_price = people.t2.price,
    all_date = people.t2.date, 
    all_adr = people.t2.adr,
    all_usl_name = people.t2.usl_name
```

Comment: I don't use constant strings, i should to take it from t2

Comment: @Actticus, it's not constant, have you tried the code

Comment: 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: @Actticus, you can check now

Comment: I create a new SQLQuery and copypaste your code, and nothing against

Comment: @Actticus, it also seems to me that you are doing something wrong - it would be great if you create your table structure https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e040d1e0648975b8b31a926d0c24c79f -then we can check it where is the actual problem belongs

Comment: It was hard
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d114bb1b12a34e40cb4219c891c758f

t1 = allsitesdb
t2 = avitodb

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

For SQL

```
 UPDATE A
 SET 
    A.id_avito = B.id, 
    A.lnk_avito = B.link, 
    A.all_price = B.price,
    A.all_date = B.date, 
    A.all_adr = B.adr,
    A.all_usl_name = B.usl_name 
 FROM 
    people.t1  A
    INNER JOIN people.t2 B
    ON A.id_avito != B.id
    AND A.all_tel= B.tel 
    AND A.all_usl_type =B.usl_type 
where ISNULL(A.id_avito,'') ='' and A.all_usl_name like '%usl_name1%' and A.all_tel like '%tel1%' and B.id is not null and B.usl_name like '%usl_name1%' and B.tel like '%tel1%'
```

FOR MYSQL

```
UPDATE people.t1 a  
INNER JOIN people.t2 B
    ON A.id_avito != B.id
    AND A.all_tel= B.tel 
    AND A.all_usl_type =B.usl_type
   SET 
        A.id_avito = B.id, 
        A.lnk_avito = B.link, 
        A.all_price = B.price,
        A.all_date = B.date, 
        A.all_adr = B.adr,
        A.all_usl_name = B.usl_name 
where IFNULL(A.id_avito,'') = ''  and A.all_usl_name like '%usl_name1%' and A.all_tel like '%tel1%' and IFNULL(B.id,0) <> 0 and B.usl_name like '%usl_name1%' and B.tel like '%tel1%'
```

Comment: Please get new solution.

Comment: 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

Comment: Please get new solution

Comment: 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0